# Correct way to layout a form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 content">
        <h2>Network Configuration</h2>      
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbDhcp" value="">DHCP enabled</label>
            </div>

            <p>IP Address</p>
            <input type="text" class="input" id="inpIpAddress">

            <p>Netmask</p>
            <input type="text" class="input" id="inpNetmask">

            <p>Broadcast</p>
            <input type="text" class="input" id="inpBroadcast">


            <p>Gateway</p>
            <input type="text" class="input" id="inpGateway">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">      
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="btnSave_Click()">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But, it isn't layouted very nice. Main problem is, the labels are closer to the input above them, than they are to the input the 'belong' to:

[image]

How should I correctly layout a form like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the form in a form tag.
Give it the "form-control" class.
Group the inputs with the "form-group" class.

Comment: The `form-control` didn't do what I expected, but the rest was OK.